# Select distinct values from mysql JSON datatype where I have a certain id

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and PHP 7. I have a table where one of the rows have the datatype JSON. How can I select all distinct values where the id is for example 74?

Row 1:

```
{
"70": "Apple", 
"71": "Peach", 
"72": "Strawberry",
"73": "Banana",
"74": "Kiwi"
}
```

Row 2:

```
{
"70": "Blueberry", 
"71": "Mango", 
"72": "Orange",
"73": "Pear",
"74": "Kiwi"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it now. JSON_UNQUOTE is not required. This works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`col` , '$."74"')) FROM tablename
```